# Express.js just won't serve static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying desperately to get it working that my express server serves statics files but I just can't get it to work... I already tried multiple attempts at solving it but none of it worked.

So my folder structure is the following:

```
App
- Web
-- public
--- images
--- css
-- Server.js
```

The code from my server is the following

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use('/static', express.static('./public'));

const server = app.listen(80, function() {
    const host = server.address().address;
    const port = server.address().port;

    console.log(`Server is running on ${host}:${port}`);
});
```

It just won't serve the files..
No matter how I change the usage of the public folder. I already tried with path.join and __dirname but none of it worked. I only get the express error Cannot GET /static ...

Comment: What URL are you trying to get your server to serve statically?  And which file in your public directory are you expecting to be served for that URL?  You have to match up three things to get `express.static()` to work properly.  You have to construct a URL you're requesting that matches the `app.use()` statement you use with `express.static()` and all that has to line up with which files are in the directory you point `express.static()` at.  All three of those must line up.  So, far you've only disclosed one of those three to us so we can't yet troubleshoot it for you.

Comment: Also, what directory from your little director hierarchy diagram is the code you show located in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen when the current working directory is not what you think it is and hence `./public` doesn't resolve to the right path. The safer way to do this is to use `__dirname`, the directory of the current file:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: Oh my god... I don't even know what to say right now... I can not thank you enough! I tried everything but just using __dirname, 'public' ... oh god //Edit: THANK YOU